# jquery submit form -> only post visible data

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have a form with a lot of radiobuttons. Depending on what you choose, different sets of buttons will be shown. Is there any way to only post the visible buttons when a user presses a submit button? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook the submit function:

```
$("#formID").submit(function() {
   //Do what you need
});
```

Then do an AJAX post where the data is $('input:visible'), or remove the hidden elements, etc.

Note: returning false prevents the submission!

Comment: Yea, but i need to redirect the user with the post data to another page, so i guess a normal post is the way to go in this case?

Comment: @Johan If you return true, it will go ahead with the submit action.  

You could use the hook to remove hidden elements `$('input:hidden')`, then return true.

Comment: if you do an ajax post and return true you will get two post backs. Removing the elements and returning true makes sense - see my answer for how to do it.

Comment: Yes, the AJAX suggestion was to only post the valid data (in this case, returning false).  When removing the hidden elements, you want to return true without the AJAX post.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter radio buttons only if you trigger form submit manually for example with
`.click(fn)` or `.submit(fn)` function.

For example

```
<button id="myFormSubmit"> <!-- in the form -->

//In js file or in the embed function
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#myFormSubmit').click(function()
     {
         var filterCheckbox1 = $('input[type=checkbox][name=checkbox1Group1]').val();
         ...
         var filterCheckboxN = $('input[type=checkbox][name=checkboxNGroup1]').val();
     });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

probably, but you should be relying on server side logic to ensure nobody is sending you 'fudged' data anyway.

You could probably do it by removing the hidden ones from the form prior to the submission like this (jQuery):-

```
$(id).remove();
```

This will remove all hidden input controls. I really wouldn't particularly recommend this however (and be very careful if you are doing this in .net as this will kill viewstate and event validation.

```
$('input:hidden').remove();
```

Comment: $('input:hidden').remove(); this removes input of type hidden and not non visible inputs.

Comment: `$("input:not(:visible)").remove()` is probably what he ment.